# adding reference and get error : System.BadImageFormatException

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iis-6, windows-server-2003, .net-framework-version

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

> Exception Details: System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file
>   or assembly 'Microsoft.Build.Framework' or one of its dependencies.
>   This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded
>   runtime and cannot be loaded.

Source Error:

> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to
>   determine why the assembly 'Microsoft.Build.Framework' could not be
>   loaded.
>
> WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF. To enable assembly bind
>   failure logging, set the registry value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1. Note: There
>   is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure
>   logging. To turn this feature off, remove the registry value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

Comment: A bit more context please ? Is this a website that has previously been working and now isn't ? Is it one that works in development but not when you deploy it to some other environment ? What version of .NET is it ? Have you checked the App Pool settings ?

Comment: See my answer on **[System.BadImageFormatException: Reference assemblies should not be loaded for execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61336306/system-badimageformatexception-reference-assemblies-should-not-be-loaded-for-ex/61702386#61702386)**.

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure all bindings are the same 32 or 64 build